# Daleif1 Theme : how to get part's title above chapter?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters, parts

I am using the `daleif1` theme, and I would like to have the `\part`'s title juste above the `\chapter`'s title on the same page.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{calc,graphicx,soul}
\usepackage{color}



\begin{document}
\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\makeatletter
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth}
\def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}}
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
  \sbox\feline@chapter{%
    \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
      \colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
    }}%
  \rotatebox{90}{%position titre "Chapitre"
    \resizebox{%
      \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
    {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
  \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
  \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
    \makebox[18cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
  }}        
\makechapterstyle{daleif1}{
  \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape\color{nicered}}
  \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{\color{black}}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{\feline@chm[2.5cm]} % taille de la box
  \setlength\beforechapskip{-1cm}
  \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedleft\underline{##1}\par}
}

\makeatother
\chapterstyle{daleif1}

\part{Part ONE}


\chapter{Chapter ONE of PART ONE}
\chapter{Chapter TWO of PART ONE}



\end{document}
```

I dont have the slighest idea how to do it. I tried to use `\printparttitle` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @daleif One for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can make `\printpartitle` to remember the current part title. I added also an interface for resetting the title to nothing.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{calc,graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\makeatletter
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth}
\def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}}
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
  \sbox\feline@chapter{%
    \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
      \colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
    }}%
  \rotatebox{90}{%position titre "Chapitre"
    \resizebox{%
      \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
    {!}{\scshape\@chapapp}}\quad%
  \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
  \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
    \makebox[18cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
  }}        
\makechapterstyle{daleif1}{
  \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\scshape\color{nicered}}
  \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{\color{black}}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{\feline@chm[2.5cm]} % taille de la box
  \setlength\beforechapskip{-1cm}
  \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \chaptitlefont\raggedleft
    {\normalfont\itshape\currentparttitle}##1\par}
}

\renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{%
  \gdef\currentparttitle{#1\\}%
  \parttitlefont{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\resetparttitle}{\gdef\currentparttitle{\strut}}
\resetparttitle

\makeatother
\chapterstyle{daleif1}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\part{Part ONE}


\chapter{Chapter ONE of PART ONE}
\chapter{Chapter TWO of PART ONE}

\resetparttitle
\chapter*{PPP} % emulate the back matter such as the bibliography

\end{document}
```

Note that I removed underlining, which has little to do with good typography. Also boldface is in conflict with small caps: there are fonts with boldface small caps, but this is a punch in the eye. Use either boldface or small caps, not both: double emphasis is too much.

[image]

If you don't want a part page, then don't issue the `\part` command, of course.

You can define

```
\newcommand\newpart[1]{%
   \cleardoublepage
   %\phantomsection % if you use hyperref uncomment this line
   \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
   \gdef\currentparttitle{#1\\}%
}
```

and use the same input as before.

Comment: Yeah Thanks. However, there is still a page with only the part's title. 

How can I remove the default part's title page ?

Comment: @Terriguest That's a very different question. Just don't use `\part` and set `\currentparttitle`.

Comment: That doesn't work ! "Part one" no longer appears!

Comment: Something is wrong

Comment: @Terriguest You should update your question; anyway, I added how to do what I think you want.

Comment: This is quiet dirty, isn't it ? However, thanks for your proposition. I appreciate that.